# No output when merge two data frame by loop

Tags: python, file, loops, io

I am merging two data frame (not pandas object, and I already know pandas solution) by loop.

```
df1
A B

df2
B C
```

I want

```
df3
A B C
```

What I did

```
for line in fi:
    b_id = line.split(',')[1]
    for line2 in fi2:
        b_id2, labels = line2.split(',')
        #print b_id
        if b_id == b_id2:
            #print b_id2
            fo.write("%9s\n" % labels)
fo.close()
```

No output.

What I checked:

1. Input correct.
2. Print out each variable in each loop.
3. The variable in the outer loop can be passed into inner loop.

---

What I checked (but may be not useful):

1. The looping method itself is ok

   `for i in range(3):
       for j in range(4):
           if i == j:
               print (i, j)`
2. Change `b_id == b_id2` to `b_id != b_id2`. I get output but not desired.

Comment: check print(labels).

Comment: Checked. No output. However, if Change `b_id == b_id2` to `b_id != b_id2`. I get output but not desired.

Comment: Because your algorithm is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try get line sub items like this:

```
b_id = [v.strip() for v in line.split(',')][1]
```

Comment: Worked. Could you discuss possible reasons for working or nor?

Comment: The splited sub item may contain blank characters, that lead to exact match failed.